# url.searchParams returns undefined in node.js

Tags: node.js

In the following node.js example:

```
var url = require('url');
var urlString='/status?name=ryan'
var parseObj= url.parse(urlString);

console.log(urlString);
var params = parseObj.searchParams;
console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
```

the property searchParams is undefined.  I would expect searchParams to contain the parameters of the search query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see in https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams

`searchParams` is a proxy to an URL object. You must obtain a new URL complete object (with domain and protocol) and then you can use searchParams:

```
var url = require('url');
var urlString='https://this.com/status?name=ryan'
var parseObj= new url.URL(urlString);

console.log(urlString);
var params = parseObj.searchParams;
console.log(params);
```

Other way is using the `query` attribute (you must pass `true` as second parameter to url.parse):

```
var urlString='/status?name=ryan'
var parseObj= url.parse(urlString, true);

console.log(parseObj);
var params = parseObj.query;
console.log(params);
```

Comment: I see now that there is a legacy URL API, and that  url.parse() uses the legacy.  What does legacy mean in this context?  will it be deprecated in the future?  Should we not code to the legacy api?

Comment: I think that deprecate is not the same than legacy. I supouse that legacy can be used without probles

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use: `var parsedUrl = new URL(request.url, 'https://your-host');` instead of url.parse

`url.parse` shouldn't be used in new applications. It is deprecated and could cause some security issues: [as stated here](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)